Same ethernaut Reentrancy answer but cause execution reverted. Why?
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract
Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted
I use the same answer on the internet to solve the ethernaut reentrancy, but it always cause this error always. Why??

You can refer to this video.

Also share the code snippet that causing the error.
